# Insert into......table Select b as a from table2 in Mysql

Tags: mysql, vb6

I migrated  from `Access` to `Mysql.Codes for vb6`.

```
mobjCmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO The123 SELECT The1 AS FirstName FROM schedule"
Set mobjRst = mobjCmd.Execute
```

And this query is not working in Mysql.

Comment: you realize insert wont return records as @Never_Mind kind of points out.

Answer (score 0):

```
mobjCmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO The123 VALUES("yOUR VALUES")"
MOBJCMD.COMMANDTEXT = "SELECT The1 AS FirstName FROM schedule"
Set mobjRst = mobjCmd.Execute
```

You must divide two CMD

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify column for `The123` table

```
mobjCmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO The123 (FirstName) SELECT The1 AS FirstName FROM schedule"
Set mobjRst = mobjCmd.Execute
```